# How to set up route variable based on rails 3.1 environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In production, our rails 3.1.4 app is deployed to suburi server_ip/by. The deployment to suburi /by requires appending the /by in front of the custom method 'view_handler' (for recording viewing history) when calling link_to. Here is an example in rails production:

```
<%= link_to 'Projects', "/by/view_handler?index=1&url=#{projects_path}" %>
```

In development or test environment, however, '/by' is not be needed (will cause error) and the link_to looks like:

```
<%= link_to 'Projects', "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{projects_path}" %>
```

In routes.rb, we have:

```
  match '/view_handler', :to => 'application#view_handler'
```

Is there a way to setup in rails environment or routes.rb only and not changing the rails code itself for suburi deployment? Or how can we append the suburi in rails production only for the link_to?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
  scope(Rails.env=='production' ? '/by' : '') do
    resources :foos
    ....
  end
```

Comment: Put everything in routes.rb into the scope? What's does the scope do? Thanks.

Comment: It accepts options for path (by default), controller, module. Say, you're about to define an optional locale (like site.com/`en`/resources/5). How would you do this? Would you prefix each of your resources? With scope you can do it this way: `scope '(:locale)' do ... end`.

Comment: The scope did not work for root "/". No match. Our system has been setup for suburi deployment in passenger (nginx) and scope may have conflict with that. thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work for root '/'? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Of course you don't have it if you put everything inside your scope. If you want your user to be redirected to `/by` path when he reaches the `/` path then just add the following line: `match '' => redirect('/by') if Rails.env=='production'` OUTSIDE your scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand this correctly, but I can think of two things to try:

1) put your production route in front of your development route in routes.rb. Rails will try to match it first, and if you are in dev/test it will fail, then try to match the dev/test route and succeed. If you are in production, it will of course match that first route.

2) wrap both routes in a conditional statement, using `Rails.env.production?` to determine which route to draw based on the environment, e.g.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  match #production route
else
  match #dev/test route
```

Comment: Did you mean in production matching the following: if Rails.env.production? match '/by/view_handler', :to => 'application#view_handler' else match '/view_handler', :to => 'application#view_handler' end

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you are trying to do with those routes correctly.

Comment: After change, the url returned is http://server_ip/view_handler?index=1&url=/by/manufacturers and did not work. It is the same as what returned before change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did jdoe's solution work? I think both of our answers would have the same outcome (although @jdoe's is more appropriate, in my opinion); it would be educational for me to know if I was wrong.

Comment: jdoe's not so far. There is routingError for "/". No match. May need to define a global constant as prefix for passing var through url which creates problem here. jdoe's solution may be good at controller level. However it is hard to make it work for the whole app because of the conflict with passenger setup for suburi deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we decided to use for the broken routes problem. In initializers, my_constant.rb is created with:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  SUBURI = "/by"
else
  SUBURI = ''
end
```

Before each and every /view_handler, add SUBURI. For example,

```
<%= link_to 'Projects', "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{projects_path}" %>
```

becomes:

```
<%= link_to 'Projects', SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{projects_path}" %>
```

The SUBURI should be added to each and every url which passes variables. The solution works so far.